# How should I convert cell arrays data into single cell arrays separately in a "for" loop

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, matrix, cell-array

I had several (500) files which I imported it into Matlab. There are 500     cells and each cell has data of size  {5000 by 2} each. I want to save 
       them separately into arrays like M and N in a loop. like M(i) and N(i) so that i can do any kind of processing or fitting with the data within the loop.

```
                   k=1:500
                 value(k) = {mydata{k}(:).data};
                  IV{1,k}=value{1,k};
                  A(k)=cat(1, IV{1,k});
                  M(k)=A(:,1);
                  N(k)=A(:,2);
```

If I check it , "H = cat(1, IV{1,4});" concatenation command works perfectly for saving into single arrays. But it's not working into loop. I think the problem lies in the correct usage of cell array contents.

Answer (score 0):

I like cell2mat in situations like this. https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html
I would turn your cell into an array, you might be able to avoid a for loop entirely.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. "cell2mat (IV{1,1})" .It shows an error "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object. Could you please provide something in detail?